# Default keyboard events for a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

If I press the space bar in my `NSTableView`, and I have a column with check boxes, is the checkbox supposed to be automatically selected?

In other terms, what are the default keyboard events of a `NSTableView`?
Does the default behavior consist only of the arrow keys changing the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's how it works. -performClick happens on the cell, if it is un-ambiguous.

corbin

Comment: try providing a bit more information in your answer to get up voted. For Example: Does the default behavior consist only of the arrow keys changing the selection ?

Comment: So, just to be sure, if I press the space bar the checkbox is automatically selected ?